# How to prove the inequation $\int_{c}^{d}f(x)dx ≤\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$?

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann integrable with $ [c,d]\subseteq [a,b]$. Additionally, $f\geq 0$.
Prove that the following inequality is true:$$\int \limits _c^df(x)\,dx\leq \int \limits _a^bf(x)\,dx.$$Ideas:
We know from the assignment that $f$ has to be restricted on $[c,d]$.
From there, maybe work with different definitions?

Comment: If $f,g\colon[a,b]\to\textbf{R}$ are Riemann integrable functions with $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, do you know how to prove that $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\le\int_a^b g(x)\,dx$?

Answer (score 3):

If $[c,d]\subset [a,b]$ then $a\leq c<d\leq b$. Then, we can split the main integral like this:$$\int \limits _a^bf(x)\,dx=\int \limits _a^cf(x)\,dx+\int \limits _c^df(x)\,dx+\int \limits _d^bf(x)\,dx$$and using the fact that $f(x)\geq 0 ~\forall x\in [a,b]$ you get the inequality$$\int \limits _c^df(x)\,dx\leq \int \limits _a^bf(x)\,dx.$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$\int_a^b f(x)~\mathrm{d}x=\underbrace{\int_a^c f(x)~\mathrm{d}x}_{\geq0}+\int_c^d f(x)~\mathrm{d}x+\underbrace{\int_d^b f(x)~\mathrm{d}x}_{\geq0}\geq \int_c^d f(x)~\mathrm{d}x.$$